# Terminating app due to uncaught exception gs url is not the same as my Firebase url

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

When I attempted to run and test my button functions I get a crash saying;

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Provided bucket: ****-37f61.appspot.com does not match the Storage bucket of the current instance:
****-716f1.appspot.com'
```

The `37f61` url is my url in Firebase so I don't know what is going on.

I did change the url link to the latter and it ran just fine however when I attempted to create a test user I can't see my user and I'm thinking it is because it's not attached to the url that is actually my project ID.

So not sure just simply changing the url is the fix or is there something wrong with Firebase? I'm a noob so please take it easy on me if I'm not including all details needed.

Expected result is for me to be able to see my test users in my Firebase database.

They do not show up in cloud or real time. Do I need to get off the free Firebase? I show that I still have allotment for downloads so not entirely sure this is the issue either.

It's just weird to me that xcode error says I should be using a different url/project ID that is not associated with my project. The first name of the url is the same but the alphanumeric characters are differ.

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Comment: The error message indicates that the Firebase client can't find the bucket that it is configured to read/write on the project that it's connected to. You might want to download a fresh `GoogleService-Info.plist` and re-add that to your app.

Comment: Thank you Frank, greatly appreciated I will try that.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work Frank. Even the existing Google plist had the correct userID in there still don't can't wrap my mind around why it's pulling a different gs url. here is the entire error:

Comment: Ok, actually got it to work after a few times of adding. Had to remove the iOS app from the project and add it back in and the re-downloaded the google doc. I can now see where I created a user under the Authentication section in Firebase but cannot see any users under the Database section. Any ideas on this?